# NSURLSession background tasks: when to call the handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession: completionHandler?

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I'm using an NSURLSession to upload multiple video files.

The `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` method is called several times, seemingly after each task completes. I store the completionHandler that's passed to this method so that I can invoke it later.

My question is this: do I invoke it each time the above application delegate method is called? Or do I invoke it only when my background session's `[tasks count] == 0`? When I do the latter the app crashes in the background with this info in the console:

```
Application Specific Information:
<BKNewProcess: 0x134d48400; com.vimeo; pid: 2141; hostpid: -1> has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x134d49500> id: 1679-3230372B-D4E5-44A1-A8DD-221CA8E6EECE name: com.apple.nsurlsessiond.handlesession com.vimeo.app.BackgroundSessionIdentifier process: <BKNewProcess: 0x134d48400; com.vimeo; pid: 2141; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 30.000000 reason: backgroundDownload owner pid:1679 preventSuspend  preventThrottleDownUI  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}
```

I have read many StackOverflow and blog posts on background sessions and their intricacies, and I see conflicting information regarding the above question.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: the latter idea sounds good, but you should handle concurrency on that counter, may be with GCD or Notifications...

Answer (score 1):

The docs for `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` say to call it there.  I've been doing that just because they said to and I haven't seen any related problems.